# WPF Listbox scroll down

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

Lets say i have a listbox with many items so that a vertical scroll comes up, but i have hidden the scroll bar with

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```

Is there any way i can add a button that would scroll down for me? iv tryed to add

```
Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
```

to a button but that didnt have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell WPF where to start looking for the command handler. Without telling it, it will start looking from the `Button` and not find anything that handles the `LineDownCommand`. Unfortunately, setting it to the `ListBox` will not suffice because the `ScrollViewer` is *inside* the `ListBox` as part of its template, so WPF still won't find it.

Setting it to one of the `ListBoxItem`s is naff, but works:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="_listBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="_listBoxItem">One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=_listBoxItem}">Scroll Down</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A better way to do this would be to either re-template the `ListBox` and stick the `Button` inside the template, or to wire up the `CommandTarget` in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I had an app where I wanted to manually control the scrolling of a ScrollViewer.  Basically, I got a reference to the ScrollViewer and then used the ScrollToHorizontalOffset() method to control the scrolling.  Below are the blog posts where I explain the process I used:

http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/fun-with-the-wpf-scrollviewer.html

http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/more-fun-with-wpf-scrollviewer.html